# Regex to Match range of IP addresses

Tags: regex

I am wantin to match IP address that are from 10.0-29.x.x, 10.31-39.x.x, and 10.41-253.x.x.
Of the lines below, I want to capture the 3rd line and below.

```
network 10.40.5.0 0.0.0.255
network 10.255.5.0 0.0.0.255
network 10.23.3.0 0.0.0.255
netowrk 10.273.255.0 0.255.255
```

So the way it will work, is if there is a match, it will set a flag that the configuration is invalid. I may have 10 invalid lines, or just 1. It doesn't matter.

Comment: So how is it going for you? What have you tried? What problems are you observing with your current solution? Please provide additional information about your current attempts (I assume you have made several before asking, so just include the most relevant ones) and what problems you are having with those attempts.

Comment: Regexes are for matching patterns, not checking numeric values.  Use a regex to find likely IP addresses, and then parse them in your language of choice and check their numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

Regex are not designed to do math.
However, you can try something like [3-4]{1} if you want a 3 or a 4.
For bigger processing you might have to match it first with a general IP regex, then process it with any language.

Answer (score -1):

The core of your problem is a regex that matches these number ranges: 0-29, 31-39, 41-253

An extended regex that matches this is:

`^network 10\.([0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[1-9]|4[1-9]|[5-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-3])\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+`

The regex is divided in these steps:
0-9, 10-19, 20-29, 31-39, 41-49, 50-99, 100-199, 200-249, 250-253

A shell script that would work is:

`if {
    cat input_file |
    egrep -q '^network 10.([0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[1-9]|4[1-9]|[5-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-3]).[0-9]+.[0-9]+ ' 
   }
 then
  echo action if matched
 else
  echo action if not matched
fi`